# How would I go about making an object look like it was made of branches?

Tags: rendering

Currently, I'm trying to create a render of a game, and the game has this arch that looks as if it was made of branches, see here (1): [image]

Now, I have the arch shape set up but I cant seem to replicate the texture that is making it look like branches (2). Any idea how?
[image]

Comment: i don't think that this is a texture...

Comment: removed the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with a curve, give it a *Bevel > Object* that is made of several circles, play with the radius (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>) and tilt (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>) of the curve vertices:

[image]

Once you're good, convert your curve to mesh and begin to deform the branches:

[image]